# локализация функции os.popen() в Python

Tags: python

Применяю функцию os.popen('dir') и выводятся символы в непонятной кодировке, как применить к данной функции кодировку utf-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Консоль Windows по умолчанию работает в кодировке cp866, а `os.popen` вывод консоли декодирует кодировкой cp1251.

1 вариант решения - закодировать обратно кодировкой cp1251, потом декодировать кодировкой cp866:

```
import os

text = os.popen("dir").read()
print("До декодирования:")
print(text)
print("="*80)
print("После декодирования:")
print(text.encode('cp1251').decode('cp866'))
```

Результат:

```
До декодирования:
 ’®¬ ў гбва®©бвўҐ C ­Ґ Ё¬ҐҐв ¬ҐвЄЁ.
 ‘ҐаЁ©­л© ­®¬Ґа в®¬ : 94D8-FA1E

 ‘®¤Ґа¦Ё¬®Ґ Ї ЇЄЁ C:\Users\user

02.12.2020  12:52    <DIR>          .
02.12.2020  12:52    <DIR>          ..
02.12.2020  12:52    <DIR>          .vscode
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Contacts
12.05.2021  09:31    <DIR>          Desktop
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Documents
26.02.2021  15:52    <DIR>          Downloads
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Favorites
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Links
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Music
10.03.2021  17:39    <DIR>          Pictures
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Saved Games
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Searches
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Videos
               0 д ©«®ў              0 Ў ©в
              14 Ї Ї®Є  13я888я589я824 Ў ©в бў®Ў®¤­®

================================================================================
После декодирования:
 Том в устройстве C не имеет метки.
 Серийный номер тома: 94D8-FA1E

 Содержимое папки C:\Users\user

02.12.2020  12:52    <DIR>          .
02.12.2020  12:52    <DIR>          ..
02.12.2020  12:52    <DIR>          .vscode
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Contacts
12.05.2021  09:31    <DIR>          Desktop
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Documents
26.02.2021  15:52    <DIR>          Downloads
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Favorites
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Links
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Music
10.03.2021  17:39    <DIR>          Pictures
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Saved Games
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Searches
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Videos
               0 файлов              0 байт
              14 папок  13 888 589 824 байт свободно
```

---

2 вариант: вызывать [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) с указанием кодировки консоли в параметре `encoding`:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(["cmd", "/c", "dir"], encoding='cp866')
print(result)
```

Это аналогично запуску через [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) и ручному декодированию вывода команды (`stdout`) из набора байт в строку нужной кодировкой:

```
import subprocess
sub = subprocess.run(["cmd", "/c", "dir"], capture_output=True)
print(sub.stdout.decode('cp866'))
```

Результат:

```
 Том в устройстве C не имеет метки.
 Серийный номер тома: 94D8-FA1E

 Содержимое папки C:\Users\user

02.12.2020  12:52    <DIR>          .
02.12.2020  12:52    <DIR>          ..
02.12.2020  12:52    <DIR>          .vscode
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Contacts
12.05.2021  09:31    <DIR>          Desktop
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Documents
26.02.2021  15:52    <DIR>          Downloads
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Favorites
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Links
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Music
10.03.2021  17:39    <DIR>          Pictures
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Saved Games
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Searches
02.12.2020  12:26    <DIR>          Videos
               0 файлов              0 байт
              14 папок  13 888 589 824 байт свободно
```

---

3 вариант: перед вызовом `os.popen` переводить консоль в кодировку cp1251 вызовом команды `chcp 1251`:

```
import os

os.system("chcp 1251")
text = os.popen("dir").read()
print(text)
```

---

В идеале нужно не явно прописывать конкретную кодировку, а получать кодировку консоли с помощью функции winapi [`GetConsoleOutputCP`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleoutputcp), ее можно вызвать с помощью модуля `ctypes`, пример:

```
import subprocess
from ctypes import windll


console_encoding = "utf-8"
console_code_page = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()
if console_code_page != 65001:
    console_encoding = f"cp{console_code_page}"

result = subprocess.check_output(["cmd", "/c", "dir"], encoding=console_encoding)
print(result)
```

Более-менее кроссплатформенное получение кодировки консоли:

```
import platform

console_encoding = "utf-8"

if platform.system() == "Windows":
    from ctypes import windll

    console_code_page = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()
    if console_code_page != 65001:
        console_encoding = f"cp{console_code_page}"
```

Для Windows кодировка будет определяться через функцию `GetConsoleOutputCP()`, для других платформ будет считаться равной `utf-8`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in os.popen('dir'): 
      print(line.rstrip().encode('cp1251').decode('cp866'))
```

Comment: `os.popen('dir')` возвращает текст в cp866 декодированном в cp1251, перекодировка в utf-8 ничем тут не поможет

Comment: Значит опционально поставить нужную кодировку: line.rstrip().encode('cp1251').decode('cp866') Исправил в примере.