# Почему некорректно выводятся символы в Windows 10, при использовании subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

Программирую на Mac OS и Linux.
Но для моего проекта нужен Windows, так как пишу под эту ОС программу.

Использовал библиотеку subprocess, но почему-то здесь выводится непонятно что.

Помогите разобраться, в чем проблема.

```
import subprocess

'''Вызов команды/сохранение команды в переменную'''


def subprocess_command(*args):
    x = subprocess.check_output(*args, universal_newlines=True)
    return x


print(subprocess_command('ipconfig'))
```

Вывод программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял, неправильно выводятся именно русские буквы. В других ОС такого не было.

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1295401/1365 Если через check_output делать, то нужно параметром кодировку консоли указать `encoding='cp866'`

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В комментариях ответили.

Я не знал, что в Винде консоль работает в другой кодировке.

Вот исправленный вариант.

```
import subprocess

'''Вызов команды/сохранение команды в переменную'''


def subprocess_command(*args):
    x = subprocess.check_output(*args, universal_newlines=True, encoding='cp866')
    return x


print(subprocess_command('ipconfig'))
```

Comment: Забыли уже все, что Windows - это надстройка над MS DOS )  Но какие-то вещи до сих пор об этом напоминают.