# Python декодинг из powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Подскажите как получить текст на русском, есть код , берёт информацию из AD

```
def name(self, name):
    command_cdsid = subprocess.Popen(['powershell',
                                f"Get-ADUser -identity '{name}' -properties Name | ft Name"],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

    out_cds = command_cdsid.stdout.read()
```

Вместо русского языка выходят символы

Comment: Попробуйте использовать кодировку cp866: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/subprocess_example/ping.py#L15

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @gil9red я бы еще попробовал кодировку через соответствующий параметр указать: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=encoding#popen-constructor

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [локализация функции os.popen() в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1295264/1365)

Comment: @insolor, идея, но у меня текущая винда английская, поэтому не смог проверить на кракозябры в кириллице :(
@Артем, попробуйте указать в `Popen` параметр `encoding='cp866'`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, все получилось

Comment: @Артем, пожалуйста :) Оформите, пожалуйста, сами ответ и примите его :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось

```
def cdsid_name(self, name):
    
    ping_res = Popen(['powershell', f"Get-ADUser -identity '{name}' -properties Name | ft Name", ], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    text = ''
    for line in ping_res.stdout.readlines():
        text += line.decode('cp866')
```

Comment: Спасибо, что оформили :) А вы могли бы еще проверить вариант с `encoding='cp866'`? Думаю, будет как-то так `ping_res = Popen(['powershell', f"Get-ADUser -identity '{name}' -properties Name | ft Name", ], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, encoding='cp866', text=True)` + `out_cds = command_cdsid.stdout.read()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    def get_name(self, name):
    ping_res = Popen(['powershell', f"Get-ADUser -identity '{name}' -properties Name | ft Name", ], shell=True, encoding='cp866', stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    out_cds = ping_res.stdout.read()
    print(out_cds)
```

Спасибо  gil9red так проще, работает, у меня подобное не получилось до этого