# Не отображается кириллица в консоли PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Подскажите, как включить отображение кириллицы в консоли PyCharm?
В версии 2020.1 все отображалось корректно, а в версии 2022.2 вместо кириллицы отображаются кракозябры. Т.е. если в коде есть ошибка, но не самого Python, а как бы ошибка консоли windows, то текст ошибки отображается в неправильной кодировке.
Т.е. у меня есть простейший код, пример специально с ошибкой:

```
import os

dwnnw = 'ifconfig wlan0 down'
os.system(dwnnw)
```

в VC Code при запуске ошибка отображается корректно:

> PS F:\my_python_repo\vnutr> & F:/Programs/Python310/python.exe f:/my_python_repo/vnutr/test/test.py
> "ifconfig" не является внутренней или внешней
> командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
> PS F:\my_python_repo\vnutr>

А в PyCharm отображается следующее:

> "ifconfig" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
> ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

Уже все перепробовал, что смог нагуглить,

- coding: utf-8 -*- в начало файла добавлял
- console font менял
- export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8:surrogateescape в Environment varialbe прописывал
- File-Setting-Editor-File encodyng везде utf-8 выставлял,

ничего не помогло.

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1295401/1365

Comment: А других способов решить проблему нет? Не хотелось бы в каждый скрипт на питоне дописывать код, чтобы в консоли корректно инфа выводилась. В настройках PyCharm никак это не решить?

Comment: Переустановка версий PyCharm не помогла, попробовал поставить 2021, попробовал поставить обратно 2020.2, попробовал разные версии Python, все равно в консоли неправильная кодировка, а версия PyCharm 2020.2 некорректно определяет версию Python, вместо 3.10 определяет как 3.1

Comment: Попробовал в настройка Editor-File Encoding наоборот выставить

Global Encoding: <System Default: windows-1251>
Project Encoding: <System Default: windows-1251>
часть информации в консоли начала отображаться корректно, но не вся:```’ҐЄгй п Є®¤®ў п бва ­Ёж : 1251
"ifconfig" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Process finished with exit code 0
```
Я правильно понимаю, что изменение кодировки с utf-8 на windows-1251 не есть гуд, т.к. потом могут возникнуть проблемы при деплое и запуске на стороннем сервере?

Comment: Еще пробовал добавить в файл pycharm64.exe.vmoptions
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
в начало и конец файла, не помогло

Comment: Сюда тоже смотрел
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-4177/Cyrillic-characters-in-the-build-log-garbled-codepage-mismatc
но что нужно сделать не понял

Comment: Как раз вариант с определением кодировки консоли самим скриптом и декодирование этой кодировкой - универсальный рабочий вариант, а ваши попытки как-то настроить IDE, чтобы чудом заработало - это костыль. В принципе и то и другое костыль, но определение кодировки - более надежный костыль, не требующий каких-то дополнительных действий и настроек руками.

Comment: Это в принципе не проблема с IDE, а фундаментальная проблема Windows, в котором в 2023 году в консоли все еще используется кодировка cp866 родом из 90-х. И chcp не помогает, потому что некоторые утилиты все еще будут считать, что кодировка консоли cp866, и писать кракозябры в консоли.

Comment: А что в итоге нужно прописать в скрипте, чтобы кодировка была правильная?

Comment: Смотрите примеры в ответе по ссылке в первом комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло это !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, словами, что именно вы предлагаете. прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit].

Comment: Действительно помогло