# output subprocess - проблема кодировки

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

я занимался с удаленным управлением консолью windows и отправкой полученного ответа на сервер, но столкнулся с такой проблемой - на сервер отправляется не output из cmd, а какие-то иероглифы.

Я пробовал переводить с китайского на русский, или с японского, но результат был ошибкой.

```
            elif command == 'system':
                self.sock.send(enc("Start Console..."))
                while command != 'exit':
                    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
                    self.sock.send(enc(dec(output)))
                else:
                    self.sock.send(enc("Exit Console"))
```

код у меня примерно такой, я думаю что это дело не в приеме команды - принтовал все отображается прекрасно, а в модуле subprocess или в кодировке самой консоли

Comment: кодировка в консоле винды oem866, можно попытаться также использовать модуль chardet

Comment: Вот это почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1295401/260769

Comment: По ссылке реально важный ответ, все работает