# Почему utf8 не может декодировать byte-тип?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Код в 3 строки лишнего ничего нет

```py
import subprocess

res = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig")
print(res.decode())
```

но почему я получаю это?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Alisher\Documents\GitHub\Backdoor\web\victim.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(res.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Я уже везде копался, многие предлагали вместо utf8 использовать ISO кодировки, но не помогает. Ошибки не получаю, но текст состоит из непонятных символов. Как мне это исправить? Какие данные вам нужны чтобы помочь мне?

**Windows 10
Python 3.10.6**

Comment: что выведет `print(res)`?

Comment: См. этот ответ: [локализация функции os.popen() в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1295401/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях дали ссылку на ответ, спасибо!

```
import subprocess

res = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig")
print(res.decode('cp866'))
```

Исходя из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1295401/1365) я сделал вывод, что нужно декодировывать в кодировке cp866.

Answer (score 0):

Используется не та кодировка, для ее автоопределения используй:
`encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()`
или вывод командной строки `chcp`

Comment: Под windows `sys.getdefaultencoding()` возвращает кодировку cp1251, а консоль работает в кодировке cp866. chcp - да, но проще тогда уж `GetConsoleOutputCP` через ctypes вызвать.